# Git master home directory

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I've accidentally made my home directory the master. How do I undo this?

Note: every time I open up terminal now it declares that my home directory is (master). I don't want my home directory in github, just a few subfolders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the git directory that is hidden inside of your home directory. In the terminal enter the following:

```
cd ~
sudo rm -R .git
```

Note: THIS WILL REMOVE ANY GIT HISTORY FOR YOUR HOME DIRECTORY. This will not remove any files in your home directory but it will remove git tracking from your home directory which is what I assume you want to do.